# Rounding corners nav bar

Tags: html, css

Hi Im having troubles rounding corners on my navigation bar, when I write - 
`border-radius: 15px;`  it round all the corners of the `<a>` but I want only to  round of the `<li>` so only the margins of the whole toolbar.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYhBe/14/).

thanks

**EDIT**

only want home and contact to be rounded

Comment: sry, but neither your question nor you fiddle is precise enough to indicate what you really want...

Comment: how can , and why can you want to round `li` and NOT `a`? Its the same thing in your fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This also works:

```
ul#list-nav li {
   border:2px solid blue;
   float:left;
   overflow:hidden;
}

li.first{
   border-top-left-radius:15px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
}
li.last{
    border-top-right-radius:15px;
   border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
}
```

[Here is the **updated** fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYhBe/31/).

Comment: @ppaul did you get what you wish for?

Answer (score 2):

To round the corners of the first and last li elements.  Try

```
:first-child and :last-child selectors
```

Check out the **live Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/HYhBe/33/

Answer (score 1):

Add two new classes; one that rounds the left corners and one that rounds the right corners and apply these to the first and last element respectively.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFZwq/)

```css
.round_left {
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;   
}

.round_right {
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;   
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="round_left">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">THE WAY WE WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="round_right">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link updated - http://jsfiddle.net/HYhBe/24/

ul#list-nav li  -> float:left & overflow:hidden;

you can remove display inline. li is a block level element.

```
ul#list-nav li {
   border-radius: 15px; 
   float:left;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: only want home and contact to be rounded?

Answer (score 0):

-- For updated question --

Remove border-radius property from 'ul#list-nav li a' and add to your CSS file:

```
ul#list-nav li:first-child a{ border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;} 
ul#list-nav li:last-child a{ border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;}
```